# Setting the stay awake while plugged in option programatically in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set the "Stay Awake" check box under Developer Options in Settings in Android programatically.

I am using following code

```
Settings.Global.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, 0);
```

and I have following two permissions added in my manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

I am using android 4.2.2 to compile the project in eclipse and then running on my tablet which is having Android 4.1.2

When I run the apk crashes and I see this exception in Logcat..

> E/AndroidRuntime(6596): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.provider.Settings$Global

Any suggestions what is going wrong or how to achieve the above functionality? Many thanks!

Comment: @Blacklight He's using exactly the answer from that question and it's not working.

Comment: It is not duplicate. The above thread do not mention about class not found exception plus the question there had a typo as instead of using Settings.Global it was using Settings.System. However I am already using the correct way which is Settings.Global

Comment: Alright, sorry about that!

Comment: no problem @Blacklight. They do look similar enough to cause confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok Just found the answer for this. I was compiling Settings.Global in Android 4.2.2 but on actual device it was 4.1.2 and looks like Android just moved Stay_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN from System to Global after api level 16. so System will work in API level 16 but Global will work afterwards.

Here is the summary below. Hope this helps someone!

```
if (currentapiVersion <= 16)
{
    Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB);
}
else
{   
  Settings.Global.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB);
}
```