# Automatically configure Android settings?

Tags: android

At work, we have an Android-based infotainment system that we're constantly deploying new versions to, on a half-dozen different test benches. The deployment script does the moral equivalent of:

```
for apk in ${apk_files}; do
    adb install -r ${apk]
done
```

After this, we need to *manually* execute the following steps:

1. Set the home app to be one of our just-installed applications (*Always*, not *Just Once*)
2. Become a developer, and enable the *Stay Awake* option
3. Select the Google TTS engine for text-to-speech functionality rather than Pico

Executing these steps after each deploy is a giant PITA. People often forget one or more steps, and leave the test bench in a non-working state. This results in a bunch of 'bogus' bug reports that waste everbody's time.

Is there some way (using `adb`, perhaps) that we can automate these steps?

Comment: Do you have root on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can disable other home apps with `adb shell pm disable ...`. I don't think there's a command line option to set apps as default. I remember looking into this before and there was a "preferred application" XML file where this was stored. If you want to look into it, the magic happens in `PackageManagerService.addPreferredActivityInternal()`. Looks like it writes the data to a file on disk: `package-restrictions.xml`. I suppose it's possible you could figure out the format thereof and write the file (you'd need root).
2. This is controlled by a system settings, "stay_on_while_plugged_in". You can set it using `adb shell settings system put ...`.
3. The TTS engine is stored in a secure setting, "tts_default_synth". You can see the value like,

   ```
   $ adb shell settings get secure tts_default_synth com.svox.pico
   com.svox.pico
   ```

   And you can set it with `adb shell settings put secure "tts_default_synth" <the value>`.

I noticed that if the value was not been previously set, when you get the value using the `settings` command you get `null` and it's not listed in `settings list`, even though there is a default value. As of Android 6 (I think), settings are no longer in a DB but rather are stored in XML files in `/data/system/users/0/settings_*.xml`. You can see the values therein.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it _totally_ puts me on the right path—thank you! I'm still puzzling through item #1, but your suggestion for item #3 worked perfectly. For item #2, I had to use `adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 1` instead (I guess this became a global rather than system setting for API level > 16, at least, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130358/setting-the-stay-awake-while-plugged-in-option-programatically-in-android).)

Comment: Hmmm. I was looking at an Oreo device. For (1), the jist is  to disable all other launches then your launcher becomes the only option. Editing the package restrictions file probably isn't reasonable. Good luck.

Comment: Indeed! What finally solved item #1 for me was: `adb shell pm disable com.example.android.home`. After that, 'our' home app starts automatically. *Perfect*!